# PHP/MySQL sort inside GROUP

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a case where I have to group results from table by brands and then order by some other column.

I get my brands from an array. 
The problem is that when I group by brand this group is sorted by ID (inside group). 
Is there a way to sort (order by) inside group?

Here is my array and mysql query.

```
$laptop_brands = array("Acer", "Apple", "Dell", "HP-Compaq", "IBM-Lenovo", "Sony", "Toshiba", "ASUS", "Fujitsu", "Gateway");

$get_videos_query = "SELECT * FROM users_video WHERE location = 'location_1' AND brand IN ('" . implode("','", $laptop_brands) . '\') GROUP BY brand ORDER BY FIELD (brand, "Acer", "Apple", "Dell", "HP-Compaq", "IBM-Lenovo", "Sony", "Toshiba", "ASUS", "Fujitsu", "Gateway"), official DESC';
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to order by official first and then by brand?

Comment: No I want to order by this order from array and then group by brand and then all together order by official column. Official column contains 1 or 0. So I would like to order by this array, group by brand and then show first all the elements which have 1 in official column. Make sense?

Comment: The sorting of the result is done after the aggregation so the order you specify will not affect the result of the GROUP BY. From what I can understand of your explanation, you are trying to modify what the GROUP BY will return through sorting... which will not work

Comment: OK, is there some other way to achieve this goal? Some sort of workaround?

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense.  How can you "SELECT * ... GROUP BY brand" (ignore the order by for the moment)?  Do you want only one random row for each brand, sorted via your array, then sort that by `official`?

Comment: OK I get that something is wrong with the query :) I want to get all rows from location_1 but grouped by brand and sorted by array and official

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM
>    (SELECT * FROM users_video WHERE location = 'location_1' AND brand IN ('" . implode("','", >  $laptop_brands) . '\') GROUP BY brand ) AS P
>    ORDER BY FIELD (brand, "Acer", "Apple", "Dell", "HP-Compaq", "IBM-Lenovo", "Sony", >"Toshiba", "ASUS", "Fujitsu", "Gateway"), official DESC

you can select from your result then order them

Comment: Thx for reply but I get the same result :( Are ">" signs there in purpose? I had to remove them in order for query to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. 
Thx everyone for notes and ideas.

So this is the query I've used to get correct result:

```
$laptop_brands = array("Acer", "Apple", "Dell", "HP-Compaq", "IBM-Lenovo", "Sony", "Toshiba", "ASUS", "Fujitsu", "Gateway");


$query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users_video WHERE location = 'location_1' AND brand  IN ('" . implode("','", $laptop_brands) . '\') ORDER BY official DESC) as my_table_tmp GROUP BY brand ORDER BY FIELD (brand, "Acer", "Apple", "Dell", "HP-Compaq", "IBM-Lenovo", "Sony", "Toshiba", "ASUS", "Fujitsu", "Gateway")';
```

Thx all, especially to morteza kavakebi