# MySQL: How to return the most recent row of each unique number

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

In the table below, I'm not sure how to do this but how do I go about writing the query which returns the **latest** row for each unique PhoneNumber?

```
PhoneNumber    MessageText               ReceiveTime        
-------------  ------------------------  -------------------
+639148186649  Delivery please           2013-03-19 01:12:55
+639148186649  I need this item          2013-03-22 02:15:01
+639148186649  I need more of this item  2013-03-23 12:01:02
+639194357455  How much for this...      2013-03-24 16:36:33
+639194357455  What time do you open?    2013-03-24 17:55:07
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

```
SELECT s1.PhoneNumber, s1.MessageText, s1.ReceiveTime FROM mytable s1 LEFT JOIN mytable s2
    ON (s1.PhoneNumber = s2.PhoneNumber AND s1.ReceiveTime < s2.ReceiveTime)
    WHERE s2.ReceiveTime IS NULL ORDER BY ReceiveTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot group by one column and return other columns that are not dependent on the group. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813680/php-mysql-sort-inside-group) for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work...

```
SELECT *
FROM PhoneTable
GROUP BY PhoneNumber
HAVING ReceiveTime = MAX(ReceiveTime)
ORDER BY ReceiveTime
```

..or you may have to do something like this...

```
SELECT PhoneNumber, MessageText, ReceiveTime
FROM PhoneTable t
WHERE ReceiveTime = (SELECT MAX(ReceiveTime)
                     FROM t
                     GROUP BY PhoneNumber
                     HAVING PhoneNumber = t.PhoneNumber)
```

Comment: This use of `GROUP BY` should not be encouraged.

Comment: Both wrong. `Error Code : 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row`